# why are aggregate functions limiting records

Tags: sql, select, limit, aggregate-functions

This should sound stupid, but I never got why aggregate functions limit the records returned to 1. More than any practical reason, this is just to know.

```
id
1 
2
3
4
```

Now `SELECT id FROM table` yields

```
id
1 
2
3
4
```

If I do `SELECT id, id, 1 AS p FROM table` it gives

```
id    id p
1     1  1
2     2  1
3     3  1
4     4  1
```

So next I assume `SELECT id, MAX(2) AS p FROM table` yields in

```
id   p
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
```

But this actually gives:

```
id   p
1    2
```

1) Why do this happen with aggregate functions and not give my expected result?

2) I found this with MySQL and SQLite. Do all databases respond the same?

3) Out of curiosity let me ask, how do I query to get a view like this:

```
id   max(id)
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You cannot execute this expression because ID is not in the aggregate function. Aggregate functions can only be used when they are the only column in the selection. This is because they return a single value and other columns mostly return more than one row.

2) I tried this in Access and got an error. (ID not in aggregate function...). I did not try this for other database systems yet.

3) You can get your result by adding GROUP BY ID at the end of the statement. This tells the system that you want to use each result of the aggregate function on every instance of ID. This enables you to use ID outside of the aggregate function.

Comment: your 3rd point is not valid since it doesnt give the output as I posted, instead it gives (1,1), (2,2), ....

Comment: This query [link](http://i46.tinypic.com/jp7m1h.png) yields this result [link](http://i47.tinypic.com/21e6vee.png). This looks exactly like your desired result.

Comment: The query in the pic will do, but my query here is `SELECT id, max(id)`. That makes the difference, can u answer accordingly?

Comment: Oh, you are right! The query for max(id) would be: `SELECT ID, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Tab1)
FROM Tab1;`

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer to 1) is: that's the way aggregates and `group by` are defined and required to work.

re 3) in most modern DBMS (just not in MySQL and SQLite) you could do this:

```
select id, 
       max(id) over ()
from your_table;
```

and that would return exactly what you expected.

To get what you want in MySQL you need to use a sub-select:

```
select id, 
       (select max(id) from your_table)
from your_table;
```

Comment: @nawfal: it's called windowing functions and can do a lot more cool things.

Comment: why is this not even executing for both mysql and lite?

Comment: @nawfal: because those two don't support windowing functions.

Comment: oops, i read it `in most modern DBMS (not just in MySQL and SQLite) `

while it was `in most modern DBMS (just not in MySQL and SQLite) ` :)

Comment: do you know how to go abt my 3rd question for MySQL and SQLite?